# Why my API Management not autorize my application using AD B2C?

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I'm developing a cloud application that use AD B2C as OpenID Connect Provider.

Below my configuration environment's:

**AD B2C**

Inside my AD B2C I've created two applications:

- DeveloperPortal - this is used for configure authorization inside developer portal.
- MyClient - this is used for configure authorization inside.

**API Gateway**

I created one [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/). After the API importations I've added one policy like following:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myTenantAzureId}/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={myPolicies}" />
</validate-jwt>
```

**MyClient**

My client is an Angular 4 application. I'm using [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) Microsoft official library.

This is my authorization service TypeScript class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var bootbox: any;
declare var Msal: any;

@Injectable()
export class MsalService {
  public access_token: string;
  private logger = new Msal.Logger(this.loggerCallback, { level: Msal.LogLevel.Verbose });

  tenantConfig = {
    tenant: "{myTenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
    clientID: '{MyClientClientId}',
    signUpSignInPolicy: "{myPolicies}",
    b2cScopes: ["openid"]
  };

  options = {
    logger: this.logger,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
  }

  //authority = null;
  authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;


  clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    this.tenantConfig.clientID,
    this.authority,
    this.authCallback,
    this.options
  );

  public login(callback: Function): void {
    var _this = this;
    this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
      _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
        function (accessToken: any) {
          _this.access_token = accessToken;
          localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
          if (callback) {
            callback(accessToken);
          }
        }, function (error: any) {
          _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
            function (accessToken: any) {
              _this.access_token = accessToken;
              console.log(accessToken);
            }, function (error: any) {
              bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
            });
        })
    }, function (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
    });
  }

  public logout(callback: Function): void {
    this.clientApplication.logout();
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }

  private loggerCallback(logLevel, message, piiLoggingEnabled) {
    console.log(message);
  }
  private authCallback(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
    if (token) {
    }
    else {
      console.error(error + ":" + errorDesc);
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem**

If I try call one API Management's API with Authorization header with access token I obtain this error:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." }
```

But If I try access directly by Developer Portal I can call the same API with success.
[image]

Why my API Manager not authorize my application?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Are you adding the token to your http request?  example: [authentication.httpInterceptor.ts](https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/master/ClientApp/app/interceptors/authentication.httpInterceptor.ts)

Comment: Hi spottedmahn, I've try also with postman and I've checked the request with browser.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the above error is occurring because the API gateway doesn't recognize the `aud` (audience) claim for the access token that is being passed from the Angular client.

The above scenario is similar to ["Azure AD B2C: Call a .NET web API from a .NET web app"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-api-dotnet) where the Angular client is the web app and the API gateway is the web API.

I recommend you:

1) [Create an Azure AD B2C app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-api) that represents the API gateway. Enter an App ID URI for this app to identify the API gateway.

2) [Add one or more permission scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) to this gateway app and/or keep the default permission scope of `user_impersonation`.

3) [Create an Azure AD B2C app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) that represents the Angular client. You've already created this client app.

4) [Grant access by the client app to the gateway app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) so that the client app can acquire an access token to act on behalf of the signed-in user to call the gateway app.

5) [Update the `validate-jwt` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-web-app) with the app ID for the gateway app.

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">  
  <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
  <audiences>
    <audience><!-- Paste the app ID for the gateway app --></audience>
  </audiences>
</validate-jwt>
```

6) Include any permission scopes, which were added in step 2, to be issued to the client app to the `tenantConfig.b2cScopes` array.

Comment: We were using the `openid-config` url *without* `/v2.0/` for an existing ADAL Angular SPA. With that the validate-jwt function failed every time. I just tried to enter the v1.0 url AND the v2.0 and those worked for both existing clients and our updated from ADAL to MSAL library. A pity this is not somewhere documented better, or I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon

> { "statusCode": 401, "message": "Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." }

It would seem you're not sending the token from Angular app when making your http request.  One way to do this in Angular is with an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses).

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return Observable.fromPromise(this.authenticationService.getAuthenticationToken())
            .switchMap(token => {
                req = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                });
                return next.handle(req);
            });
    }
}
```

Source: [authentication.httpInterceptor.ts](https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal/blob/master/ClientApp/app/interceptors/authentication.httpInterceptor.ts)

Comment: Hi, I ensure you that I send the authorization code. Inside my application I have one interceptor that inject the token and I tried the token manually with postman.